# Is it possible to build One AST for a entire React Project by Babel?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I am learning Babel now.

And I wonder if is possible to use @babel/parser to build One AST for an entire react project.

The docs I have searched are all about one file, and I want to find a way how to recursively parse file in a project and merge AST into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

An AST is an abstract representation of source code, so this question doesn't really make sense. If you have multiple files, then you get multiple independent ASTs. If you want a single AST representing all of your files, then something would need to process all the independent files and then merge them all together in some way.

That merging is well outside the scope of Babel and is what Webpack, Rollup, ESBuild and such perform during their build process, so depending on your goals, I suppose you could use one of those to generate a single file first, and then create an AST from that single file.